# Индекс второго вхождения

Tags: python, python-3.x

Даны 2 строки. Необходимо найти индекс второго вхождения второй строки в первую.

```
def second_index(text, symbol) -> [int, None]:
    """
        returns the second index of a symbol in a given text
    """
    # your code here
    if text.find(symbol)==True:
        if text.find(symbol,text.find(symbol)+1)==True:
          l=text.find(symbol)
          text = text.find(symbol,l+1)
        else:
          return None
    else:
        return None
    return text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Example:')
    print(second_index("sims", "s"))

    # These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for an auto-testing
    assert second_index("sims", "s") == 3, "First"
    assert second_index("find the river", "e") == 12, "Second"
    assert second_index("hi", " ") is None, "Third"
    assert second_index("hi mayor", " ") is None, "Fourth"
    assert second_index("hi mr Mayor", " ") == 5, "Fifth"
    print('You are awesome! All tests are done! Go Check it!')
```

Comment: Внимание, вопрос!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def second_index(text, symbol) -> [int, None]:
    if text.find(symbol) != -1:
        if text.find(symbol,text.find(symbol)+1) != -1:
          l=text.find(symbol,text.find(symbol)+1)
        else:
          return None
    else:
        return None
    return l


print('Example:')
print(second_index("sims", "s"))
# These "asserts" are used for self-checking and not for an auto-testing
assert second_index("sims", "s") == 3, "First"
assert second_index("find the river", "e") == 12, "Second"
assert second_index("hi", " ") is None, "Third"
assert second_index("hi mayor", " ") is None, "Fourth"
assert second_index("hi mr Mayor", " ") == 5, "Fifth"
print('You are awesome! All tests are done! Go Check it!')
```

Вы были близки к истине.

1. Только метод `find()` в случае нахождения чего-то возвращает индекс,
   иначе – `-1`. Ни о каких `True` и `False` там речи не идёт
2. Возвращать всё-таки следует индекс, а не сам текст, если хотите на
   выходе `int` получить
3. Вы немного намудрили с функциями поиска. Второй поиск уже ищет
   нужное значение, нужно его сохранять и возвращать

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ , все сработало!

Comment: @Anthony Всегда рад помочь :) Отметьте, пожалуйста, один из ответов как решение.

Answer (score 2):

```
def second_index(text, symbol):
    return text.find(symbol, text.find(symbol) + 1) if text.count(symbol) > 1 else None

assert second_index("sims", "s") == 3, "First"
assert second_index("find the river", "e") == 12, "Second"
assert second_index("hi", " ") is None, "Third"
assert second_index("hi mayor", " ") is None, "Fourth"
assert second_index("hi mr Mayor", " ") == 5, "Fifth"
```